# MYSQL: Make multiple counts from one select

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to make my report faster because is taking to long to load, i was wondering if there is a way to make multiple counts from just one select.

Example, make this select wish is not going to change for the counts

```
SELECT IDS, Fecha_Recarga, Banco_Recarga, Tipo, Status, RefVerif, MontoVerif, RecargaDuplicada FROM transaccionesrr WHERE Fecha_Recarga = '2017-02-07' AND Banco_Recarga = 'BANESCO' AND Tipo = 'RECARGA' AND Status = 'PROCESADA'
```

And based on the result of this select i want to make multiple counts like

```
Count (*) WHERE RefVerif = '1' AS RefVerif
Count (*) WHERE RefVerif = '1' AND MontoVerif = '0' AS MontoVerif 
Count (*) WHERE RecargaDuplicada = '1' AS Duplicada
```

This is the Stored Procedure that i have right know

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS RECARGAS,

(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM transaccionesrr WHERE Tipo = 'RECARGA' AND Status = 'PROCESADA' AND Fecha_Recarga BETWEEN PRM_Fecha_Desde AND  PRM_Fecha_Hasta AND Banco_Recarga = PRM_Banco AND RefVerif = '1') AS VERIFICADAS,

(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM transaccionesrr WHERE Tipo = 'RECARGA' AND Status = 'PROCESADA' AND Fecha_Recarga BETWEEN PRM_Fecha_Desde AND  PRM_Fecha_Hasta AND Banco_Recarga = PRM_Banco  AND RefVerif = '0') AS NOVERIFICADAS,

(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM transaccionesrr WHERE Tipo = 'RECARGA' AND Status = 'PROCESADA' AND Fecha_Recarga BETWEEN PRM_Fecha_Desde AND  PRM_Fecha_Hasta AND Banco_Recarga = PRM_Banco  AND RefVerif = '1' AND MontoVerif = '0') AS MONTOVERIF,

(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM transaccionesrr WHERE Tipo = 'RECARGA' AND Status = 'PROCESADA' AND Fecha_Recarga BETWEEN PRM_Fecha_Desde AND  PRM_Fecha_Hasta AND Banco_Recarga = PRM_Banco  AND RecargaDuplicada = '1') AS DUPLICADAS

FROM transaccionesrr WHERE Tipo = 'RECARGA' AND Status = 'PROCESADA' AND Fecha_Recarga BETWEEN PRM_Fecha_Desde AND  PRM_Fecha_Hasta AND Banco_Recarga = PRM_Banco ;
```

Im trying to do this because i think it will be faster if you think there is a better way i will be appreciated.

I have been trying to make a solution for days but i don't find any

Comment: I don't know that much about sql but i reckon the queries would be quicker if you're storing `RefVerif` as int and not character? So you'd use `RefVerif = 1` instead of using the single quotes.

Comment: I will be trying this, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS RECARGAS,
       SUM(RefVerif = '1') AS VERIFICADAS,
       SUM(RefVerif = '0') AS NOVERIFICADAS,
       SUM(RefVerif = '1' AND MontoVerif = '0') AS MONTOVERIF,
       SUM(RecargaDuplicada = '1') AS DUPLICADAS
FROM transaccionesrr
WHERE Tipo = 'RECARGA' AND Status = 'PROCESADA' AND
      Fecha_Recarga BETWEEN PRM_Fecha_Desde AND PRM_Fecha_Hasta AND
      Banco_Recarga = PRM_Banco ;
```

Comment: The report went from 18sec to 3.5sec. Thanks

Comment: It might run faster with an index on `(Tipo, Status, Banco_Recarga, Fecha_Recarga)`.

Comment: Amazing... it went down to half a second, thanks i really appreciated

Comment: @GordonLinoff this answer really helped me with my query, thank you! I'm not sure I understand the part about the index mentioned in the comments here though. Any chance you could give me an example of how that works as it really seemed to help Carlos

Comment: @KarlHumphries . . . If you have a question, you should ask it as a question, not as a comment.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, @GordonLinoff. When I click add comments, the box specifically states I should use the comments to ask for more information or to give thanks. I did both of these here because the context made more sense than starting the question from scratch. Sorry if I misunderstood how the system is supposed to be used.